# Openstack, login to my instance

Tags: openstack

I've installed devstack, downloaded a trusty ubuntu server image, launched a heat flavor instance, created a public ssh key, ssh to my instance, all fine.

Now it may be a silly question but when ssh(ing) to the instance, how to login to the instance using the console provided by openstack dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

With the default image - you can't.
Most cloud images don't have username/password authentication enabled, and rightfully so - using key pairs is much safer. But the console will not allow you to log in with a key-pair.

For development/debugging purposes, it is a good idea to add a 'debug' user to your image, with a configured password. Just don't use this image for production, or on a public cloud.

You can, of-course, ssh into the VM, set a password for the user and then use the openstack console. Just keep in mind the security implications.